# Where am i going wrong with this array filter? Reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am mapping over some data that I am getting from a api however when i try to add the filter function i get 'currencyData.includes is not a function'

I have also tried just hard coding the array but it also still doesnt work?

I have a loading state for when i fetch data from the api which holds code from being run but i have removed it from this example as its not getting data from the api below.

The simplified version is here...

ARRAY

```
var items = [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "productName": "shoes",
          "productIdentifier": "CL001",
          "productDescription": "adidas kicks boir",
          "productPrice": 2000,
          "productStock": 200,
          "created_at": "2020-51-28",
          "updated_at": null
         },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "productName": "burger",
          "productIdentifier": "FD001",
          "productDescription": "charsiu berger",
          "productPrice": 2000,
          "productStock": 200,
          "created_at": "2020-51-28",
          "updated_at": null
         }
      ]
```

```
return(
   {items.filter(currencyInfo => currencyInfo.includes("FD001")).map((value, index) => {
        console.log(value)
        return(
              <h1 key={index}>{value}</h1>
              )
    })}
)
```

Comment: That's totally normal, cause `currencyInfo` is an object, not an array, you can't call `.includes()` on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `includes()` method determines whether an **array** includes a certain value among its entries, returning true or false as appropriate. Check this [Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

But in `items.filter(currencyInfo => currencyInfo.includes("FD001"))`, type of `currencyInfo` isn't **array** but **object**.

So you should use `currencyInfo.productIdentifier.includes()`

Answer (score 4):

**`currencyInfo` is not an array, you can not call includes on it**

Here is my suggestion:

```
return(
   {items.filter(currencyInfo => currencyInfo.productIdentifier === "FD001").map((value, index) => {
        console.log(value)
        return(
              <h1 key={index}>{value}</h1>
              )
    })}
)
```

More about [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes?retiredLocale=vi)

Comment: Ah so simple now I see the answer. Thanks :)